# Problems with simple time measurement in scala

Tags: scala

I try to "profile" an expensive method by the means of just printing the system time. I've written a small method that prints the current time in seconds relative to the start-time. :

```
object Bechmark extends App {
  var starttime = 0L

  def printTime(): Unit = {
    if (starttime == 0L) {
      starttime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
    println((System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) / 1000.0)
  }

  printTime()
  Thread.sleep(100)
  printTime()
}
```

I expect therefore that the first call to `printTime` prints something close to 0. But the output I get is

```
0.117
0.221
```

I don't understand why the first call already gives me ~120 miliseconds? What is the correct implementation for my purpose?

Comment: It takes a while for the jvm to "warm up". _I am not recommending this_ as an actual fix for your "benchmark" (there is a lot more stuff wrong with it, benchmarking is not at all as simple as you may seem to think), but, try inserting `System.currentTimeMillis` call before the first `printTime`, that'll probably "fix" your immediate issue.

Comment: You may want to use  some real benchmarking tool rather than trying to hack it yourself. Have you looked into https://scalameter.github.io/ for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned the running time of your application does not necessarily represent the actual world time elapsed. There are several factors that affect it: warm up time of the JVM, JVM garbage collection, steady state of the JVM for the accurate measurement, OS process dispatching and shuffling.
For Scala-related purposes I suggest [ScalaMeter](https://scalameter.github.io/)
that allows you to tune all the aforementioned variables and measure the time quite accurately.